# Airflow Dag run start date off by 8 hours

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

My DAG config is

```json
{
    'schedule_interval': '7 15 * * *',
    'default_args': {
        'start_date': datetime(2020, 8, 1),
    },
}
```

The Airflow running config:

```
default_timezone=utc
```

Yet, every run of the DAG has (`"Task Instance Details")` start_date: 2020-mm-dd 15:07:07`.

What am I missing? This DAG is the only thing running on my Google Cloud Composer instance.

`Version : 1.10.9+composer`

**EDIT**

Everything is working as it should. My problem is that I have a cron expression different from what I intended. I wanted 7:15, so the right cron expression should be `15 7 * * *`.

Comment: what is the expected schedule you are looking to run for your DAG vs when is it running now ?

Comment: ‍♂️  Thanks for the question. I got my cron syntax mixed up. I meant it to be `15 7 * * * *` (7:15am)

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira, It is good that you found out what you were missing. In order to further contribute to the community, I encourage you to post your last comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Airflow's `schedule_interval`'s cron expression is working as intended. My problem was that I got the minute/hour inverted in my expression, so what I expected was written wrong.

Since I wanted the DAG to run at 7:15 every day, the expression should have been

```
'schedule_interval': '15 7 * * *'
```

For more on cron schedule expressions, see https://crontab.guru/